# Java security class cast exception

Tags: java, security, rsa, encryption

Hi I am beginner in Java security, i encounter the following issue, when calling :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

I got the error :

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher cannot be cast to javax.crypto.CipherSpi`

There are 5 more jars file for a payment gateway encryption in my war file:

- cryptix-jce-api.jar
- cryptix-jce-provider.jar
- cryptix-message-api.jar
- cryptix-openpgp-provider.jar
- cryptix-pki-api.jar

Without these 5 JAR files then the **Cipher.getInstance()** works, but that is not possible because I need the JARs for payment information encryption.

Anyone out there can show me the path of how should I overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi @Wilson60, you may want to check the versions of java and cryptix.

Comment: Cryptix is dead and has been forever. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but this is project was started few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers.
In the end, I moved the 5 Jars out from WAR file to server Jars library directory and solved this.
In between there was an java.lang.RuntimeException: NYI.
It was solved using the solution from here:
http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/java-lang-runtimeexception-nyi/
Hope this helps, to anyone out there.

Once again thanks!

Comment: @Wilson60: Could you please post this as an answer (and then accept this answer), so the question is marked as "solved"?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Hi I just did what you asked for. :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and answers.

In the end, I moved the 5 Jars out from WAR file to server Jars library directory and solved this. 

In between there was an `java.lang.RuntimeException: NYI`. 

It was solved using the solution from here: http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/java-lang-runtimeexception-nyi/

Hope this helps, to anyone out there.

 Once again thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Powermockito can't enhance javax.crypto classes so you might to add following annotation at the class level:

`@PowerMockIgnore("javax.crypto.*") or     @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.crypto" })`

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue when using PowerMock in a crypto test environment

Answer (score 1):

Add this at class level `@PowerMockIgnore("javax.crypto.*")`or     `@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.crypto" })`
After adding it if it shows Jce security exception
You can download this file [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and replace the local_policy jar file and US_policay jar file in this path:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\security
```