# WAS7 with Axis getting ClassCastException: IBM Crypto's TDCNP incompatible with javax.crypto.CipherSpi

Tags: java, classcastexception, jce, ibm-was, iaik-jce

I [read](http://marc.info/?l=wss4j-dev&m=118426144803740&w=2) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914814) IBM's cryptography modules are incompatible with Sun modules, but I don't know how to force IBM WebSphere (WAS7) to use Sun modules.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.crypto.provider.TDCNP incompatible with javax.crypto.CipherSpi
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I have a JAR file called `iaik_jce_full.jar` which should supposedly work (it works elsewhere but not in WAS).

> I tried to work around this by adding the Sun libraries to my project,
>   but it seems WebSphere loads its own java classes before the
>   application's, even if the class loader `PARENT_LAST` setting is used.

This is from the first link. I have tried the same and I am using the *"parent last"* setting already.

The Websphere installation comes with a `ibmjceprovider.jar` file which contains the offending class `TDCNP`.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could remove that `iaik_jce_full.jar` from your application, since WebSphere provides JCE implementation. Check [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/JceDocs/algorithms.html) for supported algorithms.

Comment: Otherwise you will need to add your provider to the `WAS_HOME\lib\security\java.security` file and add provider jar to the jdk `lib\ext` folder

Comment: @Gas The algorithm used is `DESede/CBC/NoPadding` which doesn't appear supported by WebSphere's JCE and that's why we need `iaik_jce_full.jar` (or I could be wrong). When you say "add your provider" you mean I should add the `iaik_jce_full.jar` file to the mentioned path and include the jar file name in the `java.security` file?

Comment: Move `iaik_jce_full.jar` from your application to the `WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\lib\ext` and add `security.provider.Y=your.provider.full.package.name` to the `java.security` file, where Y would be the next available number.

Comment: @Gas I tried adding `security.provider.1=iaik.security.provider.IAIK` to `java.security` file and the whole WAS7 stopped working. When changed to `security.provider.2` (re-ordering in the original list), WAS7 resumed working again, but the problem is not resolved. I had also tried `13` (next available number), `6` (middle of existing list), `3` etc, but the result is same. The `jar` file is in `java\jre\lib\ext` folder as mentioned.

Comment: So if this doesn't work, you would have to contact developers of the provider for detailed instructions as in general using external providers is not supported in WebSphere see - [Support For Sun's JSSE or JCE Provider In WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21107270)

Comment: I'm running sample from [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/JceDocs/supported_algorithms.html) and using `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.6 (build pwi3260_26sr5ifix-20130314_01(SR5+IV36426
+IV37656+IV37419+IV38029))`. I see the following `Cipher.3DES = DESede` 
`Cipher.DESede/CBC/NoPadding = TripleDES/CBC/NoPadding` in the supported algorithm list, so you may try whether it will work for you.

Comment: Not really sure what to make of this, but we removed the `javax.crypto` package from the `iaik_jce_full.jar` archive and this **resolved the problem**. This package contained the `javax.crypto.CipherSpi` class which is being reported as incompatible by the quoted exception. *What really happened, I don't know. All I know is that, this is a solution that works.* (We are going to check whether the package removal would break something else by regression.)